# Problems with HttpClient when the function is used by various devices at same time

Tags: java, android, httpclient, httpresponse

Using httpclient (apache credentials) connection to download various bitmaps with various devices is failing.... with one is working OK, ¿why?

**I'm closing the connection properly? i'm not sure about it, i'm staring on these kind of credential http connections.**

i'm developing an app for android (java) that it is connecting to a server to download 50 bitmaps, and i'm using this function each time to download each bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap getRemoteBitmap(String url) {      
    Bitmap bm=null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    HttpResponse response; 
    try { 
         ((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope(null,-1), 
                new org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials(MagazineStatus._username, MagazineStatus._password)); 

        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url)); 
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine(); 
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
            try {                   
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                bm=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(content );
            }catch(Exception ex) {Log.e("DBF Error",ex.toString());}                 
        }else { 
            response.getEntity().getContent().close(); 
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase()); 
        } 
    }catch(ClientProtocolException cpe) {
        Log.e("ClientProtocolException @ at FPT",cpe.toString());
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Exception at FETCHPROJECTASK",ex.toString());
    } 
    return bm;
}
```

If i try to download the bitmaps with one device, it works fine, but if i try to download the bitmaps with 3 or 4 devices at the same time, then, something fails on this function because this line `bm=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(content );` is giving me a a null bitmap, and i dont understand why, because `content`, `entity`, `statusLine` and `response` are not null.

These are the values for these variables when the bitmap `bm` is null:

response:

```
"response"   (id=830078599368)  
    entity  BasicManagedEntity  (id=830078617768)   
    headergroup HeaderGroup  (id=830078599408)  
    locale  Locale  (id=830078292336)   
    params  ClientParamsStack  (id=830079041944)    
    reasonCatalog   EnglishReasonPhraseCatalog  (id=830004685872)   
    statusline  BasicStatusLine  (id=830078599344)
```

statusLine:

```
"statusLine"     (id=830078599344)  
    protoVersion    HttpVersion  (id=830004713800)  
    reasonPhrase    "OK" (id=830078599288)  
    statusCode  200
```

entity:

```
"entity"     (id=830078617768)  
    attemptReuse    false   
    managedConn null    
    wrappedEntity   BasicHttpEntity  (id=830078612272)
```

content:

```
"content"    (id=830078617792)  
    skipBuf null    
    eofWatcher  BasicManagedEntity  (id=830078617768)   
    selfClosed  false
```

**I'm doing something wrong? is the connection closed properly? can this be improved?  Any help will be apreciated.**

Thanks

EDIT:

The properly way to close the connection is to add this code?

```
content.close();
entity.consumeContent();
```

Or i have to add something more?

thanks

Comment: Can you post the full exception stack trace?

Comment: no exception, it only gives me a null bitmap... it is explained on the question

Comment: The properly way to close the connection is to add this code?

content.close();
entity.consumeContent();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading your problem description the problem seems to be on the **backend-side**. Because you are adding more clients that work independently from each other that query the backend concurrently your back-end seem to be unable to deal with multiple concurrent requests.
 
Although, there is not enough information to judge. And my conclusion is based on insufficient data.

Comment: i got the problem testing with only two or three devices, i think that the problem is not on the backend side because it must allow connections from thousands of users, and not only from one or two

Comment: i'm closing the connection properly?

Comment: No you aren't. You need to close the content which is an input stream.

Comment: The properly way to close the connection is to add this code?

content.close();
entity.consumeContent();

Comment: You can use `content.close()`, although `entity.consumeContent()` does the same for BasicHttpEntity (and does nothing for non-streaming entities) if you look at the source code.


Don't use them both.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
    HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(path) );
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());
    httpRequest.abort();
```

**Note: type of path is string.**

The problem was that once you've used an InputStream from a HttpUrlConnection, you can't rewind and use the same InputStream again. Therefore you have to create a new InputStream for the actual sampling of the image. Otherwise we have to **abort the http request**.